# How to get data from the form in Angular

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, formarray

I want to get the data from the form. The data that I receive is not correct. What is my problem?

```
public editForm: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
    'id' : new FormControl(''),
    'name': new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    'code': new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    'active': new FormControl(),
    'sequence' : new FormControl(null),
    'entryTypes': new FormArray([new FormControl(), new FormControl()])
});
```

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" formArrayName="entryTypes" [checked]="locationEntryTypeDTOs[0].enabled"/>
        {{locationEntryTypeDTOs[0].entryTypeCode}}
     </label>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" formArrayName="entryTypes" [checked]="locationEntryTypeDTOs[1].enabled"/>
        {{locationEntryTypeDTOs[1].entryTypeCode}}
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Add your complete code here to see the way you're accessing form data. I can see some issues in your code with formArrayName you can't use it for a input element because it is referring multiple elements.

Comment: Try to add `[formGroup]="editForm"` to a divs.

Comment: ` <form novalidate [formGroup]="editForm">
        <div class="form-group">`    was added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the array of entryTypes in following way.

```
<div class="form-group" formArrayName="entryTypes">
    <div *ngFor="let entryType of editForm.controls.entryTypes.controls; index as i">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" formControlName="{{i}}" />
          {{locationEntryTypeDTOs[i].entryTypeCode}}
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

And update your 'entryTypes' form element in following way. And, you have to create a separate function to initiate the 'entryTypes' if there more more check boxes and value stored in locationEntryTypeDTOs.

```
'entryTypes': new FormArray([new FormControl(locationEntryTypeDTOs[0].enabled), new FormControl(locationEntryTypeDTOs[1].enabled)])
```

Comment: Make your code in stackblitz that will be easy to identify the issue and define the form in a proper way.

Comment: Try the updated answer and it will fix the current issue in form.

Comment: @Harshana, please, not use [checked], if the value is true, the checkbox is checked, else not

Comment: Yes @Elise I thought he is trying use that separate variable locationEntryTypeDTOs to make check boxes selected or not depends on that. Is that a problem to keep that?

Comment: @Harshana, you're saying to Angular that is checked if the value of the array is true (using formControlName) and that is checked if locationEntryTypeDTOs[i].enabled at time! has no sense. When you create the formArray you can do `new FormArray([new FormControl(locationEntryTypeDTOs[0].enabled), new FormControl(locationEntryTypeDTOs[1].enabled)])` -well really normally we using a map in the way `new FormArray(locationEntryTypeDTOs.map(x=>new FormControl(x.enabled))`, but in .html we should not mixing formName and checked

Comment: thank @Harshana and @Eliseo. `'entryTypes': new FormArray(this.locationEntryTypeDTOs.map(x=>new FormControl(x.enabled)))`. in this place I have a **locationEntryTypeDTOs** still empty, although I initialize it in oninit

Comment: You have the form defined in constructor and you're initializing locationEntryTypeDTOs in oninit right? In Angular constructor call before oninit call. Use a different function return a FormControl or a FormGroup based on the requirement to initiate entryTypes.

Comment: Now **locationEntryTypeDTOs** correctly filled. But in `new FormArray(locationEntryTypeDTOs.map(x=>new FormControl(x.enabled))`  set all checkboxes as true  which is not true. If i use `new FormArray([new FormControl(locationEntryTypeDTOs[0].enabled)`, angular show an error `Error: Cannot find form control at index 1` and `message:"Cannot read property 'enabled' of undefined"`

Comment: Is locationEntryTypeDTOs a local variable for constructor ? where is the this keyword ? new FormArray(this.locationEntryTypeDTOs.map(x=>new FormControl(x.enabled))

Comment: If anyone is interested, then I solved the problem by adding a line
`this.editForm.controls.entryTypes.setValue (this.locationEntryTypeDTOs.map (x => x.enabled));`
Thanks to everyone who participates.

Answer (score 1):

```
<form [formGroup]="editForm">
  <div formArrayName="entryTypes">
      <input  [formControlName]="0">
      <input  [formControlName]="1">
  </div>
</form>
```

Or if you want iterate

```
<form [formGroup]="editForm">
  <div formArrayName="entryTypes">
      <input *ngFor="let control of editForm.get('entryTypes').controls;
           let i=index" [formControlName]="i">
  </div>
</form>
```

Other form

```
<form [formGroup]="editForm">
  <div formArrayName="entryTypes">
      <input *ngFor="let control of editForm.get('entryTypes').controls;
           let i=index" [formControl]="control">
  </div>
</form>
```